# Circles on click using WebGL renderer in three.js

Tags: three.js

I want to place a circle on an object when you click on it.

I updated [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_interactive_cubes) to work with webGL renderer (I basically changed `THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial`to `THREE.SpriteMaterial`), but not only is the circle now a square, it also glitches with the surface of the object. Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qLjzyue/) that demonstrates my problem (click an object to test).

I found some similar questions on stackoverflow, but I can't seem to make it work in my example. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are adding sprites into a moving 3d scene, easy way to do what you want is to add spheres

```
var particle = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(10,10,10),
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xff0000}) );
particle.position.copy( intersects[ 0 ].point );
scene.add( particle );
```

if you want real flat circles you will have to create a circular geometry and align it correctly to the object so it sits atop of the rectangle wall and if you want circles that do not deform when object is turned you will need some custom shader stuff